# Need help/explanation on how to properly add parameter to dynamic SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm searching through databases and I reached out to StackOverflow for some help in how to learn how to run the dynamic SQL through.

The answer I got was extremely useful but it didn't come with an explanation of what was happening exactly or why. Now I'm trying to add another parameter to the code and I'm having trouble adding it.

I would like someone to help me correct the parameter so its input correctly and explain what is going on in the dynamic SQL statement.

Lets get to the problem with the Query. Everything works great as it was correctly by another StackOverflow poster. But now I need to add where the 'ControlID' column must start with the letter Q. 
With the way I've put it in now I'm getting an error that states the column 'ControlID' does not exist. But when I check to see if ControlID is the correct column name

```
select * FROM [EDDS1111111].[EDDSDBO].[Document] where ControlID like 'Q%'
```

I do get results. So it's not an invalid column name. 
I designed this input of 'ControlID' to be similar to the way artifact ID was added earlier in the code so I'm confused as to why I'm getting this error.

```
-- this is used to add line breaks to make code easier to read
DECLARE @NewLine AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = CHAR(10)

-- to hold your dynamic SQL for all rows/inserts at once
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

-- create temp table to insert your dynamic SQL results into 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DatabaseSizes', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DatabaseSizes;

create table #DatabaseSizes(
    controlid nvarchar(128),
    fileSize DECIMAL (10,6),
    extractedTextSize DECIMAL(10,6)
)

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'' + 
    'select SUM(fileSize)/1024/1024/1024 as fileSize, 
SUM(extractedTextSize)/1024/1024 as extractedTextSize ' + @NewLine +          
    'FROM [EDDS' + CAST(ArtifactID as nvarchar(128)) + '].[EDDSDBO]. 
[Document] ed' + @NewLine +
   'where ed.CreatedDate >= (select CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,- 
(day(getdate())),getdate()),106)) and ed.controlid = '+Cast(Controlid as 
nvarchar(128))+'%' + @NewLine + @NewLine
FROM edds.eddsdbo.[Case]
WHERE name like '%Review%' and (StatusCodeArtifactID = '1780779' or 
StatusCodeArtifactID = '1034288')

--controlid always needs to begin with a Q 

-- for testing/validating 
PRINT @sql

INSERT INTO #DatabaseSizes (
    controlid,
    fileSize,
    extractedTextSize
)
-- executes all the dynamic SQL we just generated
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

As I've put the code so far I'd expect for the controlID to equal the current control ID where it would begin with a Q.
I tried to copy the part where it was done correctly so I'm a little confused. Any help to increase my understanding is greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time

There is not a column for ControlID within edds.eddsdbo.[case]. But it does exist within all databases located within FROM [EDDS' + CAST(ArtifactID as nvarchar(128)) + '].[EDDSDBO].[Document]. CreatedDate also does not exist within the .[Case] tables but does exist within the .Document databases. That is why I put the search for ControlID next to the where statement for the .Document section of the query

This is what was returned when I try to run the code.

```
Invalid column name 'Controlid'.
```

Comment: Does ControlID column exis on all tables through all databases/tables? How are you  putting this condition in the query above? I am assuming that you are trying to do this: `WHERE name like ''%Review%'' and (StatusCodeArtifactID = ''1780779'' or StatusCodeArtifactID = ''1034288'') AND ed.[ControlID] LIKE ''Q%'''`.

Comment: Verify that `edds.eddsdbo.[Case]` has a `ControlID` column.

Comment: There is not a column for ControlID within edds.eddsdbo.[case]. But it does exist within all databases located within FROM [EDDS' + CAST(ArtifactID as nvarchar(128)) + '].[EDDSDBO].[Document]. CreatedDate also does not exist within the .[Case] tables but does exist within the .Document databases. That is why I put the search for ControlID next to the where statement for the .Document section of the query

Comment: We don't have your tables with your data. No one else can debug your dynamic code without seeing exactly what it generated. So post it as an edit to your question.

Comment: It could possibly be that one (or multiple) of your database is in a case sensitive collation.  Or it could be a lot of other things.  Have you ran the code that is output from the PRINT command?  You should be able to narrow down the database that is causing the issue by doing so.

Comment: @cgoll Thank you for suggestions. Every new thing to try for debugging helps narrow down the reason for the error.